# C# JSON.Net Serialize Object sending request error

Tags: c#

Json.Net Serialize object shows error 415 when I'm sending request.

I found that may be the '\' make the request error.

have no idea how to deal with it.

Can somebody helps me?

Thanks a lot!

```
class Class1
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

class clothes
    {
        public string RequestCode { get; set; }
        public List<Class1> Parameters
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          clothes obj = new clothes();
          Class1 parameter_obj = new Class1();
          obj.RequestCode ="clothes";
          parameter_obj.name="nikee";
          parameter_obj.value="001";
          obj.Parameters = new List<Class1>();
          obj.Parameters.add(parameter_obj);
          string request_str= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

          /*request_str : "{\"RequestCode\":\"AT_QJ_011\",\"Parameters\":[{\"name\":\"employeeCode\",\"value\":\"97078\"}]}"*/


          byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request_str);
        } 
     }
```

I'm trying to let my object serialize like:

```
{
  "RequestCode": "clothes",
  "Parameters": [
    {
      "name": "Nikee",
      "value": "001"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't see a \ in your JSON. Anyway, you're probably not sending the correct `Content-Type` header value (i.e. `application/json`). Unfortunately, you haven't provided your sending code.

Comment: @John I'm not copy my whole code on it , but i'm surely having Conten-Type，Thanks you.

Comment: You're expected to provide a [mcve], which you haven't done so far. If you do indeed have `Content-Type`, then it seems like the server probably doesn't accept JSON. If this is the case, you should contact the API maintainer to ask them how your data should be formatted.

Comment: @John !  Thanks!  I've checked my Content-Type again,
I type the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" So it shows error.
And I change it to "application/json" , it's fine now!
First time sending request with api,not famiilar at this,by the way thanks a lot!